# Getting SSL error if somebody tryies to connect to my Websocket server

Tags: c++, c, ssl, websocket

I wrote a Websocket server in c++ using the openssl@3 library and the build in Socket librarys.

Everytime i try to connect from Frontend i get this error:

```
00B6571701000000:error:0A00009C:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:http request:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:345:
```

I can't really figure out what this means and Im very new to Openssl so i do not know how to fixs this problem.

This is my code: (I put it in a Class because Im writing a project and i don't want the whole code in my main.cpp)

Imports:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include "netdb.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Connection struct:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int socket;
    SSL* ssl;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
} Connection;
```

And this is the Header for the class:

```cpp
class WebSocketTCPServer{
public:
    WebSocketTCPServer();
    ~WebSocketTCPServer();

    void startServer(int port);
    void handleConnection(Connection* connection);
    void closeConnection(Connection* connection);
    void closeServer();

    void send(Connection* connection, const std::string& message);
    static std::string receive(Connection* connection);

private:
    int serverSocket;
    std::vector<Connection*> connections;
}
```

And here the definition:

```cpp
#include "../Websocket.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
WebSocketTCPServer::WebSocketTCPServer() {
    serverSocket = 0;
}

WebSocketTCPServer::~WebSocketTCPServer() {
    closeServer();
}

void WebSocketTCPServer::startServer(int port) {
    //command to create a self signed certificate: openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3650
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    const SSL_METHOD* method = TLSv1_2_server_method();
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int));
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr{};
    bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(serverSocket, 5) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "ws://localhost:" << port << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        struct sockaddr_in clientaddr{};
        socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
        if (clientSocket < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        auto* connection = new Connection();
        connection->socket = clientSocket;
        connection->ctx = ctx;
        connection->ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(connection->ssl, clientSocket);

        if (SSL_accept(connection->ssl) <= 0) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        } else {
            connections.push_back(connection);
            std::thread t(&WebSocketTCPServer::handleConnection, this, connection);
            t.detach();
        }
    }

    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}

void WebSocketTCPServer::handleConnection(Connection *connection) {
    //read msg and print it
    std::string msg = receive(connection);
    printf("%s", msg.c_str());
}

void WebSocketTCPServer::closeConnection(Connection *connection) {
    close(connection->socket);
    connections.erase(std::remove(connections.begin(), connections.end(), connection), connections.end());
    delete connection;
}

void WebSocketTCPServer::closeServer() {
    for(Connection* connection : connections) {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
    close(serverSocket);
}

void WebSocketTCPServer::send(Connection *connection, const std::string& message) {
    ::send(connection->socket, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
}

std::string WebSocketTCPServer::receive(Connection *connection) {
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    int valread = recv(connection->socket, buffer, 1024, 0);
    return {buffer, static_cast<size_t>(valread)};
}
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

> ... SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:http request:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:345:

This means that your server gets a plain HTTP request (or ws://), not a HTTPS request (or wss://). Thus this specific problem is not in your server, but that the frontend accesses the server in the wrong way.

Comment: So the frontend also needs a SSL cert. Or do i just have to change from ws:// to wss://?

Comment: i tryied this:
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://192.168.1.23:12312");

Comment: this results in an error

Comment: @PixelCoin: *"frontend also needs a SSL cert"* - No. *"change from ws:// to wss://"* - yes, this is it. But make sure that the certificate is actually valid for what you give in the URL (192.168.1.23 in your case) and that the certificate is trusted in the client.  "this results in an error"* - which error exactly, where (client or server)?

Comment: This is just my local address. Im hosting the Socket server on the same device as the Webpage. The error is just "can't connect to server" and the cert i create:

Comment: with a command that i found on the internet lol

Comment: openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

Comment: @PixelCoin: *"can't connect to server"* - which suggests that the URL to the server  you use in your code is wrong or that the server is not started.  *"with a command that i found on the internet lol ... openssl req ..."* - which says nothing about the actual content of the certificate. Based on the lack of useful information it looks like that you don't really understand what you are doing which suggests that neither the content of the certificate matches the URL you use nor that you've added it as trusted into your client. But - none of this has anything to do with what you originally asked